# Use API Resource within controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to use an API resource within a controller? I have a resource that looks like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
    ];
}
```

And when I use it via HTTP requests, in a controller as a response like this:

```
public function getUser($id)
{
    return new UserResource(User::find($id));
}
```

The response is as expected because that's the intended usage, right?.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
}
```

But if I call the resource within a controller, to use it in a view, like this:

```
public function showUser($id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser($id);

    return view('user.show', [
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

The `$user` variable has all the fields of the `User` model, bypassing the `toArray()` method of the resource.

What I want to achieve is a consistent way of showing user fields across the app (especially because of the relationships and field renaming) whether is via API or in blade views.

I've tried `$user->toArray($request)` and `$user->jsonSerialize()` but that only applies to the first level of the resource. The relations are still a complex object with more keys and feels like overcomplicates (more) this issue.

Is it possible or is there another, more suitable way of doing it?

Comment: Well, API resources are intended for, y’know, APIs. If you want a consistent representation of an object, you can either use the model’s existing `toArray()` method, or some form of view presenter-like object that formats your object how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a not so clean, yet functional solution:

```
$users = json_decode(UserResource::collection(User::all())->toJson());
```

Nonetheless, solutions are still welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```php
$users = UserResource::collection(User::all())->resolve();
```